# Is there any alternative to carlosAg Excel XML Workbook Code Generator and FlexCel APIMate?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, excel, code-generation

Please HELP!

carlosAg Code Generator works nice and it's free but destroys the text inside the cells, i guess because of incompatibility with Greek in which the xml is written.

On the other hand FlexCel APIMate recognises Greek text but FlexCel library is not free..

Is there any other option for those who need to convert xls/xml to C# code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenXML SDK is a good alternative

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/erikaehrli/archive/2010/03/15/open-xml-sdk-2-0-rtm-articles-videos-code-snippets-and-resources-on-msdn.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/ee358824.aspx

Comment: does OpenXML includes a tool that converts-generates C# code out of .xml file ?

Comment: It has `LINQ` querying capabilities which should be robust enough for whatever data is needed from the sheet

Comment: finally i used both openXml SDK and carlosAg on the same xml and the the openXml did produce twice as many code lines as carlosAg...
i still donn't understand why carlosAg ruins the fonts the xml is saved in unicode format shouldn't this be enought for the library to recognise the greek letters ?...

Comment: Besides the extra lines of coded, did OpenXML not jumble the greek letters?

Comment: OpenXML and the APImate from Flexcel managed to recognice Greek... with CarlosAg still can't find a way to do it... i wouldn't search a solution but there are a lot of code lines.. even with carlosAg it's about 4.000 and with openxml almost 11.000 ...so change them one by one it's not a good idea.. any suggestions are welcome!!